Is it possible to bound the characteristic impedance of a connector pin if it's not impedance-controlled?
I'm currently assessing whether I need a feedthrough connector to be impedance controlled since it carries gigabit ethernet, but only after about 6 meters of cable. So I've made a LTSpice model with tline elements to compare when the connector is controlled, and when it's not, but I realised I did not know what I could expect if it was not controlled. In my case, for 15-20 regular signal pins of D38999 connectors, but now I am curious in general: I wonder if some of us all that would be tempted to say "it can be anything, really" could actually be wrong and that there might be a physical bound given the typical sizes and materials of connectors. Is it possible that it cannot be any higher than 377 Ohm, since free space is around that?
P.S: If it is not clear, I mean without having the CAD + materials + spending time on  an electromagnetism simulation software

Free space is a practical limit.
An example of a transmission line with a characteristic impedance higher than that of free space is an air-filled coaxial cable with a very large inner conductor relative to the outer conductor.
The ϵr or Dk has to remain at 1 while the outer coax/wire: radius must exceed a 1000:1 ratio. A skinny rigid wire supported inside a coaxial with spacers would be hard to make without increasing the Dk from the spacers and not be very flexible.
The characteristic impedance Zo​ of a coaxial conductor is given by:

Zo = 60/sqrt(ϵr) * ln⁡(r2/r1)
r2 = outer conductor inner radius
r1 = inner conductor outer radius
with the dielectric ϵr in between.


Since the dielectric is air, to achieve ϵr=1, the wire needs thin spacers to stay centred and this is not mechanically practical.
for example:
Zo=60ln⁡(r2/r1)  If Zo = 420 then r2/r1 = e^7 = 1096.6
Edit:
I would expect most of the typical circular connectors to be around 100~200 ohms with a 10:1 radius ratio.
But for Ethernet, one should test for eye pattern, added jitter or reduction in BER with adjacent pin interference added.  Then ask yourself… Are the pins longer than 10% of a wavelength? Does it need a magnetic Balun?

Great answer, thanks!

Put a  tolerance on my estimates with unknown Dk. Divide by 2 for Dk=4 with plastic, epoxy etc
